# How to flip data shape from (A, B) to (B, A)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This may be easy to do with `numpy.flip`, but it flips all elements inside array not the order.

```
data_emg = raw_emg._data * 1e6
print('Data shape =', data_emg.shape)
```

output is:

```
Data shape = (3, 5759600)
```

I want it to be:

```
Data shape = (5759600, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform transpose operation

```
n = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
print(n.shape)
# (2, 3)

# using np.transpose
nT = np.transpose(n)
print(nT.shape)
# (3, 2)

# or alternate way
nT = n.T
print(nT.shape)
# (3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your input using ".T". To save lines in code all you need is to provide it while printing:

```
data_emg = raw_emg._data * 1e6
print('Data shape =', data_emg.T.shape)
```

Or transpose it if you need it in the code:

```
data_emg = data_emg.T
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.